# Do Google's policies allow IMAP access outside of their API for business use?

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap

Google recently introduced stricter privacy policies for their Gmail API that requires a security audit for sensitive scopes, such as accessing email.  Can this be circumvented by relying exclusively on connecting to user inboxes via IMAP?

Context.io shut down because of these policies and I don't understand why they don't just connect to user inboxes via IMAP.  https://blog.context.io/context-io-deprecation-notice-ce8b77e6e477

Comment: Is this the wrong forum for this question?

Comment: I'm afraid [it is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/fnord).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technical answer is that you can't connect to GMail's IMAP accounts (in general) without using OAuth authentication; which is subject to the same technical requirements via your apps OAuth registration.

Otherwise, you have to get users to generate server specific passwords or lower the security requirements for their accounts, which is a no-go for all but the most technical of users.

By default GMail's IMAP server blocks simple password logins.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wanted to confirm we can still connect to gmail inboxes via IMAP via app-specific passwords.  It seems like a big loophole and was wondering if it were against their terms of service or something.

Comment: Sorry, I can't confirm policy.